# RegEx expression for reading specific .csv syntax

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a `.csv` file where *some* of the rows have quoted input with what is used as the separator inside them. The below line is copied directly from Excel:

```
00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp without quoted comma - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,"with quoted comma, somewhere else",,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp without quoted comma - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,"with quoted comma, somewhere else",,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
```

If you want it in string format, here you go:

```
"00013",""Comp, which does something - 999999999"","2020-01-01","Standard rgb","r k å g","","","","15","Fak E","XXX","XXX","2020-01-01","E","","","EKT","0.00","15.26","E","Å","","0","9","52"
```

I'm looking for a regex expression that will correctly extract this into column values, where the entirety of `"Comp, which does something - 999999999"`is the second column. The quoted value with separator inside isn't always in column 2.

If I copy the line(s) directly into python from the .csv and do the following

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

s = '''00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52'''
f = io.StringIO(s)

pattern = r'""'
g = io.StringIO(re.sub(pattern, '"', f.read()))
df = pd.read_csv(g, quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

Then I get the ***desired*** output, with `Comp, which does something - 999999999` as one value.

```
      0                                       1           2   ... 22 23  24
0  00013  Comp, which does something - 999999999  2020-01-01  ...  0  9  52
```

**But** if I now try to read the entire `.csv` file, say `test.csv`, by doing

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = r'""'
with open('test.csv') as f:
    g = io.StringIO(re.sub(pattern,'"',f.read()))

df = pd.read_csv(g, quotechar='"', header=None, dtype=object, encoding='UTF-8-sig')
```

I get the following output

```
             0                                   1           2   ... 22 23      24
0  ''00013,Comp   which does something - 999999999"  2020-01-01  ...  0  9  52'''"
```

So what is lost between the first procedure and the second, and how can I make the second output like the first? I have tried reading up on regex expression, but I'm completely new to the regex world.

Comment: It's possible that I'm being dense, but what you have in that first Python snippet — the `s='''...` bit — looks like valid CSV to me. Why can't you just read it as it is?

Comment: The problem is that the real files have thousands of lines, and I would prefer to use the actual file(s) rather than copying the lines and inserting triple-quotes.

Comment: But why can't you just read the files as they are? Why do you have to modify them? It's possible that I haven't properly understood what they look like...

Comment: Because the part with a comma between quotes will be separated. And I need that part to be defined as in the first example where the whole sentence is in column 1. And not like the second example where it is split into column 0 and column 1

Comment: But why will it be separated? It's within quotes, so any decent CSV reader should know not to split it. But as I said, it's quite possible that I have not grasped what your file actually looks like. Any change you could make a few lines of it available somewhere?

Comment: Well I don't know why it separates, but it does, to my frustration. 
I can't upload anything, as I'm sitting on a protected work computer. But I posted a couple more examples which should cover all different row styles. 
Simply copy into an excel sheet and you have the same file as me. 

If you are able to get my desired output with any simple command that would be greatly appreciated. I dont need a regex i just thought that was the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I put the following text in file 'test.txt':

```
00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp without quoted comma - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,"with quoted comma, somewhere else",,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,"Comp, which does something - 999999999",2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp without quoted comma - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,,,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,52
00013,Comp - 999999999,2020-01-01,Standard rgb,r k å g,,"with quoted comma, somewhere else",,15,Fak E,XXX,XXX,2020-01-01,E,,,EKT,0.00,15.26,E,Å,,0,9,
```

Then executed the following code:

```
>>> import csv

>>> with open('test.txt', newline='', encoding="utf-8') as csvfile:
...     rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
...     for row in rdr:
...         print(row)
```

And it printed:

```
['00013', 'Comp, which does something - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', '', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
['00013', 'Comp without quoted comma - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', '', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
['00013', 'Comp - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', 'with quoted comma, somewhere else', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
['00013', 'Comp, which does something - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', '', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
['00013', 'Comp without quoted comma - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', '', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
['00013', 'Comp - 999999999', '2020-01-01', 'Standard rgb', 'r k å g', '', 'with quoted comma, somewhere else', '', '15', 'Fak E', 'XXX', 'XXX', '2020-01-01', 'E', '', '', 'EKT', '0.00', '15.26', 'E', 'Å', '', '0', '9', '52']
```

**Pay attention to the `encoding` parameter on the call to `open` and the `delimiter` and `quotechar` parameters on the call to `csv.reader`.**

You can always change your extension to `.txt` and open the file up with Excel. It will then prompt you for 'File origin' where you can specify 'Unicode (UTF-8)'. Next it will prompt for `Delimiters`, which you should respond by clicking on the `Comma` checkbox. Finally, for `Text qualifier` choose the double-quote character. If you want to specify the column types, you can do that too.